# How do i get access to the System.Configuration Reference in my code?

Tags: c#

I am writing code to store custom variables into a config file.
A black.exe.config XML file exists. Following this tutorial the Class should
be accesible from within my code.

I tried to rebuild the solution but it didn't work. The System.Configuration
is referenced in the project.

black.exe.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <appSettings>
           <add key="StayOnTop" value="true" />
        </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IniParser;
using IniParser.Model;


namespace Black
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        string sStayOnTop;
        sStayOnTop = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StayOnTop");

        ...

    }
}
```

Error   CS1519  Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration //

Error   IDE1007 The name 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Try like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StayOnTop"].ToString();`

Comment: You can't set a variable like that outside of a method or property. Do: `string sStayOnTop = ConfigurationMana......` and also get the value as Hossein says (though you don't need ToString()), you don't want to use `Get`.

Comment: Or you can set the field's value within a method.

Comment: It seems to me that Visual C# doesn't see the class System.Configuration even though i added it as resource like told in the tutorial.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/815786/how-to-store-and-retrieve-custom-information-from-an-application-confi

Comment: No, if you added the reference correctly then your only problem is the syntax error. You can't write code like that at the class level - *it is invalid c#*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write code like that at the class level. You can fix it by overload the `constructor` or the `Form_Load`

```
namespace Black
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        string sStayOnTop;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sStayOnTop = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StayOnTop"];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Now i understand. Didn't know. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["StayOnTop"].ToString()